# Scipy minimize objective element-wise

Tags: python, scipy, vectorization, minimize

I am trying to apply a scipy minimizer to a vectorized objective function that takes multiple np.arrays as arguments. In this example I want to element-wise minimize `obj(x,p)` with respect to `x` while taking `p` as fixed. With `p = np.array([2,3,4])` the minima should be 2, 3 and 4.

But

```
import numpy as np
from numba import vectorize, float64
from scipy.optimize import minimize
xinit = np.array([1,1,1])
p = np.array([2,3,4])

@vectorize([float64(float64,float64)])
def obj(x,p):
    return((x-p)**2)

minimize(obj, x0 = xinit,args = p, method='Nelder-Mead')
```

returns a `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Who can help?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What's the purpose of the `@vectorize`?  What does it do for you (or intended to do) that the undecorated `obj` would not?  Does it return a different value?

Comment: You are right! The decorator is not needed here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not immediately clear what you are trying to achieve: `(x-p)**2` is an array, so using that as an objective is not a well-defined operation (as there is no reasonable ordering to use). Perhaps you actually want the squared distance between the two parameters? I.e. what amounts to

```
def obj(x, p):
    return np.linalg.norm(x-p)**2
```

This will work and find the proper minimum, but at this point the `vectorize` signature is no longer valid; the callable can still be JIT compiled with Numba if you desire though.

Comment: I would like to find the minimum `x` for each element in the `obj` array. Ideally without looping...

Comment: Sounds like looping would be the natural thing to do then; you want to reinitialize everything (including the NM simplices) in that case. It should be rather unpainful as well, as what you are looking to do would boil down to `np.array([minimize(obj, x0 = xi, args = pi, method='Nelder-Mead').x[0] for xi, pi in zip(xinit, p)])`.

Comment: And of course the `numba.vectorize` decoration then works completely fine, but it does end up being redundant (as the implementation of NM evaluates each vertex independently).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your trick completely solved my problem! And its quite quick!